# An example Dev Edition account with many VisualForce and Apex in it?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Anybody know of example Dev Edition account that is heavily customized and has extensive usage of VisualForce and Apex? I decided that the best way to teach VisualForce would be to have access to an account that has many customization made in it and extensive usage of VisualForce.

EDIT: If not a direct access to an account, something which I can import into my account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there are *many* examples, but the [Dreamhouse App](http://www.dreamhouseapp.io/) currently includes [3 example Visualforce pages](https://github.com/dreamhouseapp/dreamhouse-sfdx/tree/master/force-app/main/default/pages). It is however mostly focused on Lightning UI, so you won't get a lot of Visualforce from it.

Another option could be the [Salesforce.org Nonprofit Success Pack](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus). That has many more [Visualforce pages listed in Github](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/tree/a239688334570c59ac71b31454f7485eaa3ca472/src/pages).

Both of these will have paths for installing in an Org.

Otherwise, I'd say start with the [Visualforce specific Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules#tag=tag-pages) such as [Visualforce Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_fundamentals).

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer was extremely helpful. I liked the Nonprofit Success Pack code.